# Is there a way to use PowerShell to test if an AD user is locked out?

Tags: powershell, authentication, active-directory

I need to check if a particular AD user is currently locked out using PowerShell.

Comment: `Search-ADAccount –LockedOut`

Comment: Or `Get-ADUser -Identity <SamAccountName> -Properties LockedOut`

Comment: Depending on the size of your AD environment you might also want to consider querying a specific AD server by using the `-Server` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Olaf.  Option 2 is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Search-ADAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/search-adaccount?view=windowsserver2019-ps) with the `–LockedOut` argument.

```
PS C:\> Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | FT Name,ObjectClass -A
```

Would print

```
Name           ObjectClass
----           -----------
Patti Fuller       user
```

Comment: Youd could improve your question by adding the suggestion of Jonathan Waring in the question comments. looks like it would be a better one becase of the "_check if a_ **particular** _user is locked out_"